# Groovy use own quote character in CSVWriter from Grails Plugin

Tags: csv, groovy

I want to use CSVWriter from Grails Plugin, but I don't know how to change the default quote and value seperator. I also want to know to how to avoid a header line.

My code (which is not working)

```
Writer writer = new StringWriter()
CSVWriter w = new CSVWriter(writer, {
    testdata.eachWithIndex { row, index ->
        "${row}" {it."${row}"}
    }
})
w.quote = "'"
w.valueSeperator = ";"
```

w.quote is not working

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/pedjak/grails-csv/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/csv/CSVWriter.groovy) is the source code of the Grails CVS Plugin. It seems to me that contrary to  [CSVReader](https://github.com/pedjak/grails-csv/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/csv/CSVReaderUtils.groovy) the CSVWriter doesn't accept in constructor options to override delimiter etc.

```
CSVWriter(Writer writer, Closure definition)
```

**UPDATE**

As hinted in the comment I tried to change the quote character in a subclass. This works, but unfortunately **there is a problem with the header line** (containg two **null* strings). I'm not able to resolve this.

```
import org.grails.plugins.csv.CSVWriter 
  /* Groovy Version: 2.4.4 */
@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class MyCSVWriter extends CSVWriter {

  private columns = [:]
    private cachedQuote
  private cachedQuoteEscape
  private cachedQuoteReplace
  private cachedValueSeperator
  private cachedRowSeperator
  private producers
  private lastProducer
  private headingsWritten = false  


  protected getQuote() {
  "'"
  }

  protected getQuoteEscape() {
  "'"
  }

  protected getValueSeperator() {
  ","
  }
  protected getRowSeperator() {
  "\n"
  }

}

def sw = new StringWriter()
def b = new MyCSVWriter(sw, {
  col1 { it.val1 }
  col2 { it.val2 }
})

b << [val1: 'a', val2: 'b']
b << [val1: 'c', val2: 'd']

println  b.writer.toString()


'col1'null'col2'null
'a','b'
'c','d'
```

Comment: Looking at the Grails CSVWriter code from your answer it looks like you are supposed to extend it if you want to have custom quote/escape characters.

Comment: With the code above, I managed to override the quote, but the header line is wrong `'col1'null'col2'null` (containg null strings).`'a','b' 'c','d'`

Comment: Sorry your sample code looks right to me.  Please attach a sample data that you are testing against.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I now used CSVWriter from opencsv where I simple can user this constructor: CSVWriter w1 = new CSVWriter(writer1, del, quote)

Comment: @Peter I thing this is a good decision. Please if you find my answer usefull mark is as +1 (may be this wil attract someone to resolve the problem with the nulls in the header).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solve the problem, but I've had the same issue and I've been able to change, for instance, the value of `valueSeperator` setting the property `cachedValueSeperator`. So in your example, you can do:

```
CSVWriter w = new CSVWriter(writer, {
    testdata.eachWithIndex { row, index ->
        "${row}" {it."${row}"}
    }
})
w.cachedQuote = "'"
w.cachedValueSeperator = ";"
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I used CSVWriter from opencsv where I simple can user this constructor: CSVWriter w1 = new CSVWriter(writer1, del, quote)